# Lightswitch - Grid inside another Grid

Tags: grid, visual-studio-lightswitch

Tell me please if I can put small grid (subform in Access terms) inside big grid and make them both editable.

I cannot show you screenshots because of not enough reputation

Well, I've managed myself. Just added new Datagrid in parent DataGrid Row. But I have another question now - how to hide headers in this child datagrid? I have search box that I do not need, and a counter in the bottom :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're gonna have to make a custom control if you don't want the data grid column headers.

Instead, have you looked at the List-Details screen? It might not be the layout you're looking for, but it might work for you.